# accessing variable from other file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to tidy my code into py files, I have the gui with 4 QLineEdit boxes and I want oerson.py to access the inputted vales when the btnNewPerson is clicked. This is summary code which works in a single file, but I am trying to break it up into classes which are manageable.

publicationgraph.py

```
[other imports ...]
from person import Person
class PublicationGraph(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.resize(600, 400)
    self.title = 'title'
    self.left = 10
    self.top = 10
    self.width = 440
    self.height = 280
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    #self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    self.lePersonFirstName = QLineEdit('First Name', self)
    self.lePersonFirstName.move(40, 40)

    self.lePersonLastName = QLineEdit('Last Name', self)
    self.lePersonLastName.move(40, 80)

    self.lePersonInitials = QLineEdit('Initials', self)
    self.lePersonInitials.move(40, 120)

    self.btnNewPerson = QPushButton('Add Person', self)
    self.btnNewPerson.move(40, 160)
    self.btnNewPerson.clicked.connect(Person.new)
```

person.py

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def new(self):
            name = self.lePersonLastName.text()
            firstName = self.lePersonFirstName.text()
            lastName = self.lePersonLastName.text()
            initials = self.lePersonInitials.text()*
```

Comment: What's the question/issue you have?

Comment: some feedback??

Answer (score 1):

A program organically is not a set of files but is the interaction of objects that are created based on the classes defined in the modules, libraries or files, so your question should be: How to pass the parameters to an object of the class Person? And in this case it is through methods like the constructor.

**publicationgraph.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from person import Person

class PublicationGraph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

        self._persons = []

    def init_ui(self):
        self.lePersonFirstName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lePersonLastName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lePersonInitials = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.btnNewPerson = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Person')
        self.btnNewPerson.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(widget)
        flay.addRow('First Name', self.lePersonFirstName)
        flay.addRow('Last Name', self.lePersonLastName)
        flay.addRow('Initials', self.lePersonInitials)
        flay.addRow(self.btnNewPerson)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        first_name = self.lePersonFirstName.text()
        last_name = self.lePersonLastName.text()
        initials = self.lePersonInitials.text()

        p = Person(first_name, last_name, initials)
        self._persons.append(p)
        print("Persons: ", self._persons)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PublicationGraph()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**person.py**

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, fistname, lastname, initials):
        self._firstname = fistname
        self._lastname = lastname
        self._initials = initials
```